# Loop through large collection of documents and update it if it's found in a file very fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

what i am trying to do is loop through a large collection of documents very fast what i want here is time efficiency , so i have a file that has like 30M lines , and a collection of emails could be 500k or 1M max, i want to check if that email exists in that file then update an array in that document , thinking about this for days not finding something useful : this is my code , but it takes alot of time like 20 min or more , i want to speed it up to do it as fast as possible maybe 2 minutes or less , blew i am working with cursors in mongodb ;

```
 for await(const email of MailBox.find({})) {

    const child = shell.exec(`LC_ALL=C fgrep -m 1 -w ${email.box} file.txt`);

    if(child.stdout.replace('\n','') === email.box){
        email.supp.push(1)
        await email.save()
    }

}
```

can someone give me some advice please

EDIT : after i took some of the advices from the comments this is my new code but still take so much time , with 200k of documents and a file that has 10M lines ,using callback it got faster but not as desired

```
 for await(const email of MailBox.find({}).select('box supp')) {
   shell.exec(`LC_ALL=C fgrep -m 1 -w ${email.box} file.txt`, async function(code, stdout, stderr) {
        if(stdout.replace('\n','') === email.box){
            mail.supp.push(offer)
            await email.save()
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest grep, but I see you are already using it. the only other way I suppose you could make this faster is doing your shell.exec asynchronously and using a callback when it returns. I think it's likely, but I don't know for sure if that's the biggest consumer of time.

Comment: Are these the only tools you have at your disposal? If so, there are some clever things you could do with Mongo itself by creating a temporary collection based on emails scraped from this file with a regex, and cross-collection queries. As ControlAltDel mentioned above, ditching promises will net you some pretty big increases in perf, at a cost of LoC and maybe readability.

Comment: Probably better to just do this with a bash script and look to parallelize some of the work rather than brining it into Node taking the parsing hit and doing synchronous loops and replacements (you're using `await` on each task). Also is `email` a large document? You probably can select fewer fields than all of them in the document.

Comment: i took some of you advices selected few fields and used callback in shelljs but still not that fast , i was thinking in running it in parallel but i don't know how to that exactly , any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is mail.save?  can you batch all the push operations and save only once (or in batches)?

Comment: @user120242 email.save is when i save the document to mongodb after the push

Comment: oh, so then mail is just a typo for email?  there's one more to edit in your second code block

Comment: yes i edited it ,  i have to save the document on every push , can you clearify please how to batch it